# Unable to use sink connector inside kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I am trying to use S3 sink connector inside kafka connect , It starts and fails later .

My config looks like :

```
{
    "name": "my-s3-sink3",
     "config": {
         "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector", 
         "tasks.max":"1", 
         "topics":"mysource.topic", 
         "s3.region":"us-east-1", 
         "s3.bucket.name": "topicbucket001", 
         "s3.part.size":"5242880", 
         "flush.size":"1", 
         "storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage", 
         "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat", 
         "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner", 
         "schema.compatibility":"NONE"
        }
    }
```

My connect-distributed.properties look like:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
errors.tolerance = all
```

Complete Error log :

```
[2021-04-06 10:59:04,398] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-s3connect12-0, groupId=connect-s3connect12] Member connector-consumer-s3connect12-0-f1e48df8-76ba-49f9-9080-e10b0a34202b sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator **********.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)

2021-04-06 16:29:04
[2021-04-06 10:59:04,397] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3connect12-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)

2021-04-06 16:29:04
[2021-04-06 10:59:04,396] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3connect12-0} Error converting message key in topic 'quickstart-status' partition 3 at offset 0 and timestamp 1617706740956: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)

2021-04-06 16:29:04
[2021-04-06 10:59:04,393] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-s3connect12-0, groupId=connect-s3connect12] Resetting offset for partition quickstart-status-3 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[***************.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 1 rack: use1-az2)], epoch=absent}}. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
```

Message type :

```
{
   "registertime": 1511985752912,
   "userid": "User_6",
   "regionid": "Region_8",
   "gender": "FEMALE"
}
```

[image]

New ERROR Log :
[image]

Comment: How is the data serialised? What key and value converters are you using in your connector (or worker) config? ref: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained

Comment: Hello @RobinMoffatt Edited the Question with screenshot. Its all json . How can I figure out what key and value converters are being used in connector ?

Comment: I suggest you set the converters in the actual posted connector config, not only from docker (which should be done with env vars, not editing the property file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the Key SerDe. Per your screenshot the key data is a non-JSON string:

```
User_2
User_9
etc
```

So instead of

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

use

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

---

Edit:

Try this for your connector config, specifying the converters explicitly (as suggested by @OneCricketeer)

```json
{
    "name": "my-s3-sink3",
     "config": {
         "connector.class"               : "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
         "tasks.max"                     : "1",
         "topics"                        : "mysource.topic",
         "s3.region"                     : "us-east-1",
         "s3.bucket.name"                : "topicbucket001",
         "s3.part.size"                  : "5242880",
         "flush.size"                    : "1",
         "key.converter"                 : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
         "value.converter"               : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
         "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
         "storage.class"                 : "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
         "format.class"                  : "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
         "partitioner.class"             : "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
         "schema.compatibility"          : "NONE"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Robin, I have updated key.converter to use StringConverter but still gets the same error . [2021-04-06 12:52:06,656] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3connect14-0} Error converting message key in topic 'quickstart-status' partition 2 at offset 0 and timestamp 1617706739466: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask). key.converter.schema.enable should remain false right ?

Comment: `schema.enable` is not applicable except for the `JsonConverter`. Did you restart the Kafka Connect worker after making the configuration change?

Comment: Is there any more detail of the error after the line that you've quoted?

Comment: Updated the Question with all the logs . I am using S3 sink connector and kafka connect inside docker so spinning docker container everytime

Comment: I've edited my answer to incorporate @OneCricketeer's suggestion of embedding the converter config in the connector config itself

Comment: Hi Robin , Thanks for the update , I don't see desriaalisation error now but somehow I still don't see messages being delivered to S3 bucket .

Comment: The error log I see is:INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-buck01-0, groupId=connect-buck01]Resetting offset for partition quickstart-status-2 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[*****.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 3 rack: use1-az4)], epoch=absent}}. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState)
INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-buck01-0, groupId=buck01] Found no committed offset for partition quickstart-status-4 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

Comment: Hello @robin : I have updated Question with New error screenshot related to multipartupload

Answer (score 0):

So I am able to resolve the issue. After specifying the converters explicitly, I was able to resolve the deserialization error and then had an issue with S3 Multipart Upload which was resolved by giving Fargate task permission to the S3 bucket by attaching S3 IAM Policy to the ECS Task definition.
Thanks, Robin Moffatt for the solution above!